# Google Maps API v3 not loading map when settingCenter frequently

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, loading

this is my first post after reading for years in this beautiful community.
I'm planning on using the google maps API v3 for displaying nearby emergency services on a television over a raspberry pi in a pharmacy. For that purpose im getting the locations from an API here in germany. I chose to display the 3 closest services to the location of the display. Only one location is shown at a time (for 10 seconds using setInterval) as it will provide a higher zoom for better understanding of the location. So im calling setCenter(maps[c]) every 10 seconds. maps[c] is containing the 3 LatLong objects for the services respectively. If c is >= 2 im resetting c to 0 so the first location will be shown again. The maps are loaded every minute from the API keeping them up to date if they change. In the opening hours of the pharmacy some offers are displayed using a simple slider. In the closing hours the emergency services are shown and rotating through the maps.

The problem im having is that after a while some of the maps arent properly loaded. Sometimes only half of the map appears, sometimes they are just grey and showing the red marker im setting. I already tried triggering the resize event after each change of the map and resetting the zoom, hoping the map would get repainted using

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
map.setZoom( map.getZoom() );
map.setCenter(maps[c]);
```

However this doenst seem to work as the problem still persists. It wont show in the first few hours but after 1-3 days the maps will stop loading properly.

Any ideas how this could be solved? I already tried all of the fixes i found (triggering resize and setting the zoom again) but i didnt find any solutions so far.

Thank you for your replies. :)

Comment: Not sure why you think the **map** will change so often.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Sounds to me like you might be exceeding the free daily limit of 25,000 map loads per day: https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/

Comment: Also if you're relying on any of the APIs, they've got a free limit of only 2,500 requests per day

Answer (score 0):

Thank you duncan, i somehow overlooked that :P 
Loading the maps only once now if the adress changes and toggle the display property of the three maps in order to change what map is shown. This way they wont load everytime which looks better and avoids the problem described.